# Shared library can not access memory of a program

Tags: c++, linux, memory, shared

Sorry for my English. I have created a shared library and my program loads this dynamically.
It works ok, but the problem is that I pass a pointer to the shared library, but this can not access the pointer memory. In the other way there are no problems.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Note: I use linux, but if the idea works on other OS I will search for this equivalent

Here the code:

```
unsigned analizer::analizeText() {
std::cout << "thread started" << std::endl;
while(true)
{
    pause.lock();
    varMu.lock();
    unsigned enable = __enable;
    unsigned line   = __line;
    unsigned _colum = __colum;
    unsigned offset = __offset;
    varMu.unlock();

    unsigned begin = offset;
    std::cout << "get usafed docs" << std::endl;
    std::cout << doc->getText() << std::endl;//the program crash
    vector<document*> doc = _openDocuments->getUnsavedDocs(_openDocuments->traductDoc(this->doc)); std::cout << "relized" << std::endl;
    while (beginElements.find(_openDocuments->getChar(begin-l)) == beginElements.end() and begin > 0)
        --begin;

    word = this->doc->getText().substr(begin,_offset-begin);

    delete UunFile;
```

load library:

```
#include <iostream>

pBear::language *_language;

using namespace pBear;

void language::load()
{
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end;
    for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(languagePath); it != end; ++it)
    {
        void *hndl = dlopen(it->path().c_str(), RTLD_NOW);
        if(hndl == NULL)
        {
            std::cerr « dlerror() « std::endl;
             exit(-1);
        }
        std::function<LanguageDatas*(pBear::openDocuments*)> fun = (LanguageDatas*(*)(pBear::openDocuments*)) dlsym(hndl, "colorMaker");
        LanguageDatas *dat = fun(openDocuments);
        dataLanguages[dat->getName()] = dat;
    }
}
```

pass the pointer:

```
ana = _language->getLanguage(doc->getProyect()->getLanguage())->getAnalizer(doc);
```

**Last messages of the program:**

analize

thread started

get usafed docs

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Photos of the code - very bad idea, please paste your code as a text

Comment: Add error message too.

Comment: ok, I added the last messages of the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
std::function<LanguageDatas*(pBear::openDocuments*)> fun = (LanguageDatas*(*)(pBear::openDocuments*)) dlsym(hndl, "colorMaker");
LanguageDatas *dat = fun(openDocuments);
```

It looks like you try to find a C++ function with name `colorMaker` in that shared library. And then you invoke the result of `dlsym` without ever checking it for `NULL`.

It can be that `dlsym` returns `NULL`, hence the segmentation fault.

It is suspicious that a C++ function has a C-style name `colorMaker`. Double-check the symbol names in that shared library.

`dlsym` never throws C++ exceptions, so you need to check its return value:

```
LanguageDatas(*fun)(pBear::openDocuments*) = static_cast<(LanguageDatas(*)(pBear::openDocuments*)>(dlsym(hndl, "colorMaker"));
if(!fun)
    throw std::runtime_error("colorMaker function is not found");
fun(openDocuments);
```

Note, that you do not need to wrap the function pointer into `std::function` in order to invoke it.

Comment: The library is loaded, it is not the problem. The problem is that document *doc is a pointer from the program but the library has not rights to read this. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: sorry, I found the problem. It seems that "export var" is very dangerous for shared library. thanks